# How to use Keep and Peek with TempData attribute on auto-property

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

[TempData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio#tempdata) has been introduced as an attribute in Razor Pages in dotnet core 2.0 but there's a problem with using it with `Keep` and `Peek`. As the attribute is on the property the value is read and marked for deletion within the auto-property.

```
    [TempData]
    public string MyId { get; set; }
```

How do you use `TempData.Peek()` with the property?

Comment: Where do you want to do the `Peek` (just get the value) ?

Comment: @Shyju The value is read in the next page but that page will be posted back to and the value can't be deleted between requests.

Comment: TempData will be gone after that page where you are reading it. If you want that to be part of the form submit, you need to include that in the form submit request data (keep it inside a hidden element and submit). TempData was designed for short life purpose.

Comment: `var myId = TempData.Peek("TempDataProperty-MyId").ToString();` will work and will work consistently between redirects and postbacks. It seems odd though, as I had to inspect the data to find that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the auto-property is set in the first page with the `TempData` attribute:

```
[TempData]
public string MyId { get; set; }
```

Then as `TempData` is read in the second you can prevent it being marked for deletion by using `Peek` thus:

```
var myId = TempData.Peek("TempDataProperty-MyId").ToString();
```

This will continue to work how ever many times you post back to the second page.

Comment: How to use it? Is there any setting to make first? My TempData dictionary is empty even after putting TempData attribute on property.